# vertx - reading from property/config file

Tags: vert.x

How to read data from property files? I understand vertx uses '.json' files for storing data but not sure how to create JsonObject from property/config file.

I would like to keep, server port, connection url, db name etc. in to a config file.

Comment: http://vertx.io/blog/vert-x-application-configuration/

Answer (score 6):

you should run your verticle over `io.vertx.core.Launcher`, then you could add conf option `-conf config.panser.json`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Create the src/main/conf/my-application-conf.json with the following content:

```
{
  "http.port" : 8082
}
```

And now, to use this configuration just launch your application with:

java -jar target/my-first-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-fat.jar -conf src/main/conf/my-application-conf.json

To get the values use

```
config().getInteger("http.port", 8080)
```

Above code is now requesting the configuration and check whether the http.port property is set. If not, the port 8080 is used as fall-back.

Copied from : http://vertx.io/blog/vert-x-application-configuration/index.html

Comment: There must be a solution that works when packaged and when unpackaged.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-service-factory to  create a default configuration for a verticle.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-conf` argument with the relative path (`src/.../config.json`) to your configuration file.

E.g.

- `java -jar target/vertx-practice-1.0-SNAPSHOT-fat.jar -conf src/conf/vertx-practice-conf.json`
- `run com.ashenlive.vertx.MyFirstVerticle -conf src/conf/vertx-practice-conf.json`