# When I use vert.x to creat a route, Address already in use

Tags: java, vert.x

In the below code, I'm using vert.x to create a route

```
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.VertxOptions;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class VerticleMain extends AbstractVerticle {


    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {

        Router router = Router.router(vertx);

        router.route().handler(routingContext -> {
            routingContext.response()
                    .putHeader("content-type","text/html;charset=UTF-8")
                    .end("people");
        });
        vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8181);
    }

    public static void deployVertx() {
        String verticleId = VerticleMain.class.getName();
        VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions();
        Consumer<Vertx> runner = vertxStart -> {
            vertxStart.deployVerticle(verticleId);
        };
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(options);
        runner.accept(vertx);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        VerticleMain.deployVertx();
    }
}
```

However, when i tried executing the code again, the log is

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

If this port is used, I want to stop the process which occupied the port, and then execute the code. Is there any way to accomplish this goal?

I hope you can provide a simply example

Comment: you want to kill process who is already listening on 8181? Why? Maybe it is there for some reason. Isn't better to pass port as main argument or conf file so you can choose it?

Comment: @Francesco How can I pass port as main argument or conf file? Can you give me a example?

Comment: Well you can easily find examples over the web about passing arguments or using config files. Vertx provides its own [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438767/vertx-reading-from-property-config-file?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). But what is hanging on 8181? Could be your application itself you previously run?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is absolutely fine. please kill all the java process or restart your machine and try again. it should work fine. only one import was missing and i added that.

```
package com.americanexpress.digitalpayments.pipe;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.VertxOptions;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class VerticleMain extends AbstractVerticle {


public static void deployVertx() {
    String verticleId = VerticleMain.class.getName();
    VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions();
    Consumer<Vertx> runner = vertxStart -> {
        vertxStart.deployVerticle(verticleId);
    };
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(options);
    runner.accept(vertx);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    VerticleMain.deployVertx();
}

@Override
public void start() throws Exception {

    Router router = Router.router(vertx);

    router.route().handler(routingContext -> {
        routingContext.response()
                .putHeader("content-type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8")
                .end("people");
    });
    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8181);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you need to kill the port:

for ubuntu:

```
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:8081)
```